# What is the purpose of offset in conjunction with datetime in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm looking to work with datetime. I have some files generated every Sunday and I like to move the furthest Sunday out of the current folder eg: 2020-04-12, 2020-04-19, 2020-04-26.

I have found some examples on getting a specific date from today's date and I was able to modify it a tab bit. Eg. I can go back and get last week's Sunday with a specific date:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime(2020,4,13)
offset = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7
sunday = today - timedelta(days=offset)
#print (offset)
print(sunday)
```

I am confused by the offset variable. What is `(today.weekday() + 1) % 7` doing? I have read the Python doc and not quite wrapping my head around it. With +1, I get the date 2020-04-12, which is a Sunday, great. When I do -1 (the other thing is if I set it to `(today.weekday() - 1) % 7)`, I get 2020-04-07, a Tuesday. How did it jump from Sunday the 12th to Tuesday the 7th?

Additionally, how do I get it to jump back 3 weeks? that's where I'm also stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if today's Wednesday, then [`today.weekday()`](https://serverfault.com/) is 2, because it starts counting from 0 on Monday. Not sure why, but that's life.

So `(2 + 1) % 7) = 3`. That means that 3 days ago was Sunday. Hence your code:

```
offset = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7  # How many days ago was sunday
sunday = today - timedelta(days=offset)  # Go backwards from today that many days
```

You'll notice that if you subtract one instead of add one, that means we're going *backwards* (because we're sutracting the `timedelta` object) by *two fewer* days than before (because `2 - 1` is equivalent to `(2 + 1) - 2`, that is, two fewer days). If you started by going backwards enough days to get to Sunday, and now you're going backwards two fewer days, you'll end up on Tuesday, which is two days later than Sunday.

The easiest way to shift which week you're headed to is to set the `weeks` argument in `timedelta`:

```
n_weeks = 3
sunday = today - timedelta(days=offset, weeks=n_weeks)
```

that's equivalent to, but much prettier than:

```
sunday = today - timedelta(days=offset + n_weeks * 7)
```

Comment: Thank you!  It all make sense now.  I was beating my head against the wall because I went from offset = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7 to offset = (today.weekday() + 1) % 14 and got the 'correct' Sunday.  Then I went % 21 and got something else.